# How can I create a global object, and attach a string and a function to that object, in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How can I create a global object, attached to the `window`, and attach a string and a function to that object, in ClojureScript?

For example, an myobject that looks like:

```
{"foo": function () {..},
 "bar": "somestring"}
```

`myobject.foo` => `function () { .. }`

`myobject.bar` => `"somestring"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the JavaScript that generates an object attached to the window. 
It has too properties. `foo` which is a function and `.bar` which is a string.

```
(let [my-object (set! (.-myobj js/window (clj->js {})))
      some-func (fn [] (+ 1 1))]

  (set! (.-foo my-object) some-func)
  (set! (.-bar my-object) "something"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure why you need this, but it's very similar to the Javascript version:

```
{:foo (fn [] ...)
 :bar "something"}

(:foo my-object) => (fn [] ...)
(:bar my-object) => "something"
```

There are some important differences between the Clojure and Javascript versions

1. Clojurescript maps are immutable.
2. There's no `this` reference pointing to the "object" in the function body. Clojure maps are not objects, they are key-value pairs.

Comment: You're right, I should've specified, the question should have been how to attach a object, to the browser's window object, via CLJS.